# ASP.NET MVC Session Variables not working - remaining as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I am trying to store an object of the type 'Person' in a session variable. The Session variable is stored like so:

```
    public void SelectPerson(int ID)
    {
        Person person = db.People.Where(p => p.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();

        Session["PersonID"] = ID;
        Session["Person"] = person;
    }
```

I then try and use this session variable at  a later date, but it is always coming back as null

```
Person person = (Person) Session["Person"];
```

I am not sure why this isn't working. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Depending on Person class implementation, maybe the casting fails, and thus the returning data is null.

Comment: Is Session enabled in your configuration?

Comment: @Bardo Could you elaborate? The session variable storing the ID was a test and even though ID has a value, the session variable remains null.

Comment: @Paddy this is what I thought may be the issue - I am unsure as to what this means or how I would do it.

Comment: 1.Do any sessions work? 2.If so, does the database return a value in the code above?

Comment: @RyanSearle none of my sessions appear to be working.

Comment: @JamesLloyd Make sure you have cookies enabled in your browser

Comment: @RyanSearle cookies are definitely enabled in my browser and I've tried across multiple browsers.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary but it can't hurt to add to the web.config: <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20">
    </sessionState>

If you haven't already...

Comment: If I were you I would run a very simple test of setting a string to a session variable and try using it immediately after...

Comment: @RyanSearle the simple test of setting it to a string and trying immediately after has appeared to work.

Comment: @JamesLloyd This tells us that your sessions are working, most likely cause is that your session is being lost somewhere between setting are retrieving the variable, without more code I can only guess what your problem maybe...

Answer (score -1):

Please check what is the value that you get from this line: `Person person = db.People.Where(p => p.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();`

Try to write:

> Response.Write(person);

After you tried what I've wrote here, tell me the value that it writes.

Comment: Where exactly will this write to?

Comment: Rather than response.write, just run up the debugger and see what the result is.

Comment: @JamesLloyd He gave another option above. We just want to see what is the value that you get from `person`. You can also create a simple lable and set his text to `person` value.

Comment: person = {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Person_A20668C6E1C5A1661A623D9EEC075B8966915E87A24FF6D35AF50E7B07F06A69}

Comment: It seems proxy creation is enabled. Try to disable it in configuration and try this `var person = Session["Person"];` to check if there is any casting error.

Comment: var person still comes back as null and how would I disable proxy creation? I can't seem to find it anywhere in web.config?

Comment: As I know, the Session method can only save `string` vairables. Maybe this is the problem because you try to save in the `Session` a `Person` variable.